How to serve two different websites on one Apache Webserver without using Virtual hosts?
We use Apache Webserver on Windows to serve one web app within our software. A browser embedded in our software accesses the site on localhost. The webserver and the web content are installed on every machine running our software to avoid us having to open the server up to external IP addresses.
Now we will host a second web app with Apache. I configured this using virtual hosts, but there has been concern about the need to modify C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file to map the ServerName to 127.0.0.1 on customer machines.
How do we host two websites on one Apache webserver without using virtual host?

Create new host on different port

I'm fairly sure you still have to map the ServerName of your virtual host to an IP address in the hosts file regardless of what the port is. Or do you mean literally a second instance of httpd.exe running on a different port?

No, just add record in apache config with "virtual host" with different port. And this new host will point to different app and will be accessible via http://localhost:8000 (for example)

These days the primary concern for modifying the hosts file is malware. If this change follows the normal process it shouldn't be a "concern". Is there a reason that you aren't using DNS to define ServerName for 127.0.0.1?

Generally whatever.localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1. I never had to explicitly define such entries in a hosts file.

Thanks everyone the link from Romeo Ninov gave me the answer, all working well now with no modification of the hosts file.
